# How to use SQL query as source in ODI 12c

Tags: etl

I need to use Select Query results ( having Sub query) as source. This results needs to join with another source table.

Ex: Select A,B from (Select t1.a as A, t1.b as B from table1 t1,table t2 where t1.a=t2.b)

In 11g, we've yellow interface where we can write custom queries and invoke that into blue interface for joining with another table.

I'm looking for similar options in 12c

Comment: Why don't you try out the extract options in properties for Source physical view. You can have custom query there. #ODI12c